# How to change color in Android side menu drawer

Tags: android, menu, drawer

does someone know how to change the color from the selected sidemenuitem??? (Red marked in the image)
I use the sherlock side menu drawer...

p.s. Sorry for my bad english

here the pic http://i43.tinypic.com/5d4ith.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If thats a list view you can use

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```